# React redux mapStateToProps not set return to my props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Problem when using prop, it starts as `null` and then I use `map` but as it is `null` returns an error.

And then ends up not responding to the updated state:

```
class HomeProducts extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchProduct();
      }
    render() {
        console.log(this.props)

      const productItems = this.props.products.map( product => (
          <div className="col-md-4 pt-4 pl-2">
          <div className = "thumbnail text-center"> 
          <a href={`#${product.id}`}  onClick={(e)=>this.props.handleAddToCard(e,product)}>
              <p>
                  {product.name}
              </p>
          </a>
          </div>
              <b>{util.formatCurrency(product.price)}</b>
              <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={(e)=>this.props.handleAddToCard(e,product)}>Add to Cart</button>
          </div>
      )
      )
        return (
            <div className="container">
            <div className="row">

            </div>  
            </div>
        )
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    console.log(state);
    return{
        products: state.data.products,
        loading: state.data.loading,
        error: state.data.error
    }
  };
  const mapActionsToProps = {
    fetchProduct: fetchProduct
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapActionsToProps)(HomeProducts);
```

my reducer:

```
import {
    FETCH_SUCESS,
    FETCH_FAIL,
    FETCH_LOADING,
  } from '../constants/fetchTypes';

  const initialState = {
    loading: false,
    products: [],
    error: null
  };

  export default function productReducer(state = initialState, action) {

    switch (action.type) {
      case FETCH_LOADING:
        return {
          ...state,
          loading: true
        };
      case FETCH_SUCESS:
        return {
          ...state,
          loading: false,
          error: null,
          ...state, products: action.data
        };
      case FETCH_FAIL:
        return {
          ...state,
          loading: false,
          error: action.error
        };
      default:
        return state;
    }
  }
```

my action:

```
import api from '../../services/api';
import {FETCH_SUCESS,FETCH_FAIL,FETCH_LOADING} from '../constants/fetchTypes';

const fetchSucess = data => ({
    type: FETCH_SUCESS,
    data

  });

  const fetchStarted = () => ({
    type: FETCH_LOADING
  });

  const fetchFailed = error => ({
    type: FETCH_FAIL, 
      error
  });

  export const fetchProduct = () => {
      console.log('action')
    return dispatch => {
      dispatch(fetchStarted());

      api
        .get('/products')
        .then(res => {
          dispatch(fetchSucess(res.data));
        })
        .catch(err => {
          dispatch(fetchFailed(err.message));
        });
    };
  };
```

my combiner reducer:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import  productReducer from './productsFetch.reducer';

export default combineReducers({
    data: productReducer 
});
```

my store:

```
export default function configureStore(initialState) {
    return createStore(
        rootReducer,
        initialState,
        applyMiddleware(thunk)
    );
}
```

And I got:

> Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: Show the code in reducer, are you sure you are not setting an empty array in intialState?

Comment: Are you able to fetch the products, does the action gets triggered?

Comment: Yes i get my status

if i take my map and give console.log in props i have my array

but when I have my .map it gives error pq my array starts as empty.

Comment: i edit with my reducer.

Comment: Felipe can you add all related code to the question?  store, combineReducers, action creators...

Comment: ok i go edit now @SuleymanSah

Comment: done i edit now

Comment: The problem is me my .map

i get my this.props.products

normally

but when i first use .map it is null and then i get map undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try like this without using initialState in createStore?

```
  return createStore(
        rootReducer,
        applyMiddleware(thunk)
    );
```

It seems that when we try to initialize the state both in createStore and reducer, something is broken.

[Docs](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/initializing-state)

Comment: now the error is over, but my .map didn't work because the array starts as null

Comment: @Felipe we gave initialState in the reducer, so I guess it must work. I mean here `export default function productReducer(state = initialState, action)`

Comment: @Felipe if you want to give initialState with some products, you can give it in the reducer initialState.

Comment: But I'll start with the products as empty

and then I get the products in my backend

the problem is in it

I still couldn't solve

Comment: I get my data normally the only problem is that it starts as an empty array
and i try to give a .map to an empty array i don't know how to solve it

Comment: @Felipe we will start with an empty  products array, when we get the products from api, the state will be updated, and products will be shown in your component, I don't understand the problem.

Comment: omg got the problem

I was not showing my PRODUCTITEMS object in div

Comment: @Felipe if the problem is resolved with the help of my answer, can you please mark it as answer?

Comment: yes bro done thanks, u can help me with this warning: https://pastebin.com/zRkGVH2A

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203603/discussion-between-suleymansah-and-felipe).

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to check the `initialState` in your reducer, and see if you actually have an empty array for `products`. With that you do not have to deal with the cases where is empty in the very first load. So when having the initialState with `[]`, then you could also play around with different messages for the user, like (if array is empty, then either show LOADING (for cases when you also handle that state in your reducer) or EMPTY list when you actually finished loading the data.

Comment: but i make this on my component? i edit post with my redux

Comment: @Felipe are you using `combineReducers`? how are you exporting that reducer as `data`? I see you have there `state.data.products`, just to be sure that `data` is actually the reducer you have shared here.

Comment: @Felipe something like this https://github.com/cristofer/react-rails_with_redux/blob/master/app/javascript/reducers/index.js and https://github.com/cristofer/react-rails_with_redux/blob/master/app/javascript/reducers/todos.js , so for this example it is called `todos`, you have to make sure that yours is called `data`

Comment: yes i gave console.log and my props arrives normal
the problem is that it first arrives as null and i try to use the .map there i have error

Comment: The problem is me my .map

i get my this.props.products

normally

but when i first use .map it is null and then i get map undefined

Comment: @Felipe just protect it then, do ```this.props.products && this.props.products.map(....```

Comment: how i make this?